# Looping around VLOOKUP to delete row on success

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying loop back over data in a worksheet in Excel 365 and when certain conditions are met, delete the row the condition applies to. All is well until I use the workbook VLookUp function as a part of the final condition - I need to delete the row if any of the conditions are true or if the VLookup is successful (an error in the VLookUp would mean that the row should be kept). What I currently have is:

```
On Error Resume Next
divFile = "C:\....\workbook.xlsx"
Set divWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(divFile)
Set divRange = divWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:B274")

For i = lastRow To firstDataRow Step -1
    If Condition1 Or _
       Condition2 Or _
       WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, lcCol).Value, divRange, 1, False) Then
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
   End If
Next i
```

The above flips to the other workbook (divWorkbook) and does not do what is intended. How would I keep focus on the current workbook and sheet and apply the delete when the vlookup is successful but not when it isn't?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Try specifying the worksheet you want to delete the rows from: ex: `Worksheet("Sheet1").Rows(i).Delete`

Comment: Thanks. I did make it more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd drop the `On Error Resume Next` and instead use `Application.Match`, testing the return value for an error.

Also, as noted by @cybernetic.nomad, be more explicit about what sheet you're working on.

```
Dim shtData As Worksheet

Set shtData = ActiveSheet ' or whatever

divFile = "C:\....\workbook.xlsx"
Set divWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(divFile)
Set divRange = divWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:B274")

For i = lastRow To firstDataRow Step -1
    If Condition1 Or Condition2 Or _
       Not IsError(Application.Match(shtData.Cells(i, lcCol).Value, divRange, 0)) Then

            shtData.Rows(i).Delete

   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fashioned the solution based on your response and it worked. I did add one line `shtData.Activate` in order to keep or at least return the focus to the current sheet.